HTML links are broken in : "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4920685/how-to-calculate-the-curl-for-vec-nabla-times-hata-for-unit-vector-hat"
I have some long website links in my article:
"How to Calculate the Curl for $\vec{\nabla}\times\hat{a}$ for unit vector $\hat{a}$ in Cartesian, Cylindrical, and Spherical Coordinates" that end up formatting like:

[Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System][1]

Can I get some support on what needs to be done to fix these?  It seems to be a problem with the longer URL's that wrap around to the next line at the bottom.  The Math Stack Exchange Website should support the longer links because many of the University-level links are longer, because of the structure within the University to organize and save them for an organized web-resource.
Thank you in advance for your help!

BTW it seems a bit unusual to call something like this article - AFAICT the usual terminology in the SE network is post, question, answer.

Your original version looked like this:
<h5>Background Reference</h5>
In the article "[Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System][1]

Background Reference
In the article "[Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System][1]

I have simply added an empty line after the header:
<h5>Background Reference</h5>

In the article "[Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System][1]

Background Reference
In the article "Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System

If the header is written using Markdown rather than using a HTML tag, we do not need the empty line.
##### Background Reference #####
"[Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System][1]

Background Reference
"Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinate System

You probably want to edit the post further, since you have the same link twice immediately after each other. But I left it in the state which was close to your previous version - the only edit I made was to remove the problem you describe in the question.

Both HTML tags and Markdown can be used in posts - but it was observed a few times in the past that sometimes they do not mix well. This is worth keeping in mind.

Nice.  And thank you for your support.  I accepted all of your edits. :)
